# phpMyAdmin and mysql issue

Tags: mysql, wamp, wampserver

I am running WAMP latest version

Everything was fine.......

I opened phpMyAdmin and added a user and a password for the user

Now I can not get into phpMyAdmin unless i set authentication type to cookie

Then I can login with my user name and no password.....but I HAVE a password....

Also MySQL console will login without a password now also....

What the heck have I done?

PHP `config.ini` looks like this:

```
<?php

/* Servers configuration */
$i = 0;

/* Server: localhost [1] */
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'USERNAME';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'PASSWORD';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;

/* End of servers configuration */

$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'en-utf-8';
$cfg['ServerDefault'] = 1;
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';


/* rajk - for blobstreaming */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bs_garbage_threshold'] = 50;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bs_repository_threshold'] = '32M';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bs_temp_blob_timeout'] = 600;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bs_temp_log_threshold'] = '32M';


?>
```

Next MySQL ini file looks like this:

```
# Example MySQL config file for medium systems.
#
# This is for a system with little memory (32M - 64M) where MySQL plays
# an important part, or systems up to 128M where MySQL is used together with
# other programs (such as a web server)
#
# You can copy this file to
# /etc/my.cnf to set global options,
# mysql-data-dir/my.cnf to set server-specific options (in this
# installation this directory is C:\mysql\data) or
# ~/.my.cnf to set user-specific options.
#
# In this file, you can use all long options that a program supports.
# If you want to know which options a program supports, run the program
# with the "--help" option.

# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
#password   = MYPASSWORD 
port    = 3306
socket  = /tmp/mysql.sock

# Here follows entries for some specific programs

# The MySQL server
[wampmysqld]
port        = 3306
socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock
key_buffer = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_cache = 64
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
basedir=c:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.5.24
log-error=c:/wamp/logs/mysql.log
datadir=c:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.5.24/data
```

Literally all I did was open phpMyAdmin and added a new user

What I need to do is remove both users from phpMyAdmin

THEN

Add in a user with full privileges and a password and have that match what is in 
phpMyAdmin config.ini file

I should be able to do all of this from the mysql command console but i need some help with commands.

If I could just get a user added and put that info in phpMyAdmin config.ini file i just need to get in it and I can modify what i need to.

---

I restored SQL back to noon today and this resolved my issue however the reason I had this issue to begin with is because I was trying to load an access applications database into sql and it kept telling me I did not have access. However when I login to phpMyAdmin with the same credentials  all is well.

Comment: If you can issue a query, try `SELECT * from mysql.user` and you can see the list of user and host combinations as well as the encrypted password (if any).  Its possible to have a mysql user called 'root'@'127.0.0.1' with no password, and a user 'root'@'192.168.0.%' which does have a password.  If you are logging on from the server locally, you don't need a password.  If you are logging on from a remote system on the local network, then you would need a password.  Maybe something like this happened.  Examining the values in `mysql.user` should shed some light on this.

Comment: I cannot find that file at all -- I am in the processes of recovering the whole WAMP folder from noon today. So that should fix me. Thank goodness for backups.

Comment: It isn't a file, rather a database and table.  There is a default `mysql` database which stores things like schemas, users, and other info about the DB.  Inside your MySQL data directory, there should be a "mysql" folder which contains this database and its tables, but looking at the files directly is no help.  If you were able to connect and issue a query, you may be able to figure out why you can log in with no password.

Comment: Drew awesome advice.....problem is I am such a noob with sql it is not even funny. So I have gained access back to myphpadmin......however when I click WAMP tray icon and select myphpadmin i am prompted for user and password......this use to be automatic.....good thing is the user and password is as i remember and is as i intended as well as having all my information as it was before.....all seems well.

Comment: That's good, maybe it was a fluke, hopefully there won't be any more issues.  From PMA, try issuing `SELECT * FROM mysql.user;` and you should get a full user list.  Maybe it will contain no surprises or maybe you'll see multiple of the same users, one with a password and one without.

Comment: I only have one user listed in the database as my intention. Here is a picture http://i48.tinypic.com/kb57j8.png